# Correcting Node Height for BST in CPP

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I just need some help adjusting the height variable of ndoes in a BST, I cannot find out what is wrong with the logic in my code.

```
void BST<T>::fix_height(Node* node){
    Node* current_node = node;
    while(current_node !=nullptr){

       if(current_node ->right != NULL && current_node ->left !=NULL){
          current_node->height = std::max(current_node->left->height, current_node->right->height) + 1;
           
       }else if(current_node ->right == nullptr){
           current_node->height = current_node->left->height+1;

       }else if(current_node ->left == nullptr){
          current_node ->height = current_node->right->height+1;

       }else{
           current_node->height = 0;
       }  
       current_node = current_node -> parent; 
       print(current_node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the logic is wrong?

Comment: That last else statement should set the height to 1.

Comment: There is a test case where an assertion real_height = your_height is passed that i am failing. I have tried putting it to 1 and that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: There's no way of knowing what's wrong without you providing an example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DavidG, a leaf node has height 0 according to the definition on Wikipedia. The height is the length of the longest path between root and leaf expressed in number of edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code assumes that the children of the node that is passed as argument to `fix_height` have their heights already set correctly. If this is not guaranteed, then it already goes wrong there. But without seeing the context of the call of this function we must assume the function is only called on leaves or on nodes whose children have their height correctly set.

There is one problem inside the function: if `node` is a leaf, then the second `if` block will be entered, where an invalid reference is made to `current_node->left`.

One way to fix this, is to swap the first and the last case, and so first deal with the leaf case:

```
void BST<T>::fix_height(Node* node) {
    Node* current_node = node;
    while (current_node != nullptr) {
        if (current_node->right == nullptr && current_node->left == nullptr) {
            current_node->height = 0;
        } else if(current_node->right == nullptr) {
            current_node->height = current_node->left->height + 1;
        } else if(current_node->left == nullptr) {
            current_node->height = current_node->right->height + 1;
        } else {        
            current_node->height = std::max(current_node->left->height, current_node->right->height) + 1;
        }
        current_node = current_node->parent; 
        print(current_node);
    }
}
```

A minor thing: in C++ don't use `NULL` for null pointers. You had a mix of `NULL` and `nullptr`. Only use the latter.